# Statistical proof to exclude less frequent records from data during analysis

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, bias

I am working on reviewing the results of an automated task. For ex, To give you an idea, the data that I have to review looks like as shown below

[image]

Let's say from the downstream analytics perspective, we know that any records which occur only 10 or 20 times may not make any difference/impact on our results. However, I can't just base my argument on my judgment which is subjective in nature and I would like to know whether there is any statistical/mathematical/systematic approach that can give me that `N` value below which I don't have to review. Currently, I don't review items that are occurring less than 30 times **because it is not worth our time in reviewing items that are very rare or pointless paying money for reviewing rare items... Now, this might seem like a business decision but we have to answer as to why we chose this `N` threshold. Now since it's business, the decision can be made based on experience... But let's now think from a research perspective... From a research perspective, I need to have a systematic approach to justify the threshold that I chose. Hence am here seeking help from you folks**

So, I need an objective approach which can assist me in either of the two things listed below

1) Let me know that anything occurring less than 1 or 2 or 3% of your data doesn't make any impact in your analysis
2) Or provide me an `N` value (which could be 30,70 or 20 or whatever) and I will not review records which fall below this threshold

So basically, I am trying to retain objective nature of decision making to review or not. If you can provide any systematic/mathematic/sttistical theory to back this up, would really be helpful

Comment: Maybe tell us what is your analysis about? For example, if you were interested in finding the most rare terms, this would obviously fail. The example is dumb, but surely there are  examples where this would, or would not matter.

Comment: Exactly, the point here is I am not interested in reviewing the rare terms...What I am trying to do is compare words in two dictionaries through a string matching/fuzzy matching approach. Now that's done and it's totally possible that it may not be 100% accurate. However, to keep the data clean and accurate we are also trying to review those terms because we can't rely an automated approach because any incorrect mapping would affect our results. The automated approach above is a test that we are currently running to see how we can do this mapping efficiently.

Comment: But what we are interested in is mapping the terms in these two dictionaries. Instead of being full-blown automated approach, right now it is semi-automated which is totally fine with us as this task requires some sort of human inputs as well..

Comment: This post is in continuation of this post  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467316/justifying-the-judgement-with-a-systematic-approach-theories

Comment: Why not just draw a random sample or the records to review?

Comment: If I draw a random sample, what if I get all low-frequency records... Because it's random we don't know what will be the outcome... For ex: in a dataset of 10k records, let's say I have 10 unique terms which occurring 70 times each where as other 9300 records are occuring once each .Meaning we have 9300 unique terms and 10 terms (occurring 70 times) each leading to 700

Comment: In this case, it's important that we don't miss reviewing those 10 terms (which are occurring 70 times each)... Even if I miss rare terms from reviewing that's totally fine

Comment: *Why* is it important?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108784/discussion-between-the-great-and-tim).